# Rotate in 4 dimensions javascript

Tags: javascript, 4d

The equation for 3D rotation on z is:

```
d = degrees
newx = x*cos(d) - y*sin(d)
newy = y*cos(d) + x*sin(d)
```

So basically you replace x and y with the two axis that are not the rotational axis, but how would you do this with x, y, z, and *w*?

Comment: Do you know of [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)? Seems like you can extend that system for extra dimensions easily, but I'm not sure. Also, can you elaborate on why you want 4 dimensions?

Comment: Is'nt that what you are showing a rotation in 2D?

Comment: Wikipedia shows the rotationmatrix for R3 where you can rotate n radians around a unity-vector: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix.